# Mid-Tension Hand Grip Good For beginners?

Tags: weightlifting, strength, grip-strength

My personal trainer has suggested I work on my grip strength as he thinks that it is restricting me from reducing heavier(ie I have to lift lower weight as I do have trouble getting a good grip sometimes).

So I decided to get a hand grip tool and do it while I am watching tv. I have no clue what is good so I  just went to the store and bought a pair for $10

On the box there was no indication on the tension but now looking at the online site I see it is mid tension(not sure what the number for mid tension is)

[Mid Tension Hand Grip](http://www.sportchek.ca/product/index.jsp?productId=11613059)

I was doing it yesterday and it is not too bad on my right hand(my dominate hand). I would have to double check but I think I can almost close it. With my left hand I get maybe half way.

I am not sure if I need a lower tension or if it is good what I have. I probably will get my trainer to check it out and see as well but always good to hear other thoughts.

Also even though it came with 2 of them I just use one and do 10 reps and then switch hands as I find it a bit easier to do then.

As I side question is [this kind](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/3-Grip-Hand-Finger-Forearm-Strength-Trainer-3-Levels-Exerciser-Gym?item=160860439091&cmd=ViewItem&_trksid=p5197.m7&_trkparms=algo=LVI&itu=UCI&otn=1&po=LVI&ps=63&clkid=2788496262207477490) of design for hand grips any good?

Comment: What kind of lifts are you doing?  Also, how are you grabbing the bar?

Comment: pretty much anything with a bar bell(dead lifts, chest press, squats and etc). Um I not sure how to describe how I am grabbing the bell. I am going to assume that it is proper as I am doing all the exercises with my PT

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased 200, 250 and 300 lb grips from Heavy Grip (http://heavygrips.com/). I'm closing the 200 with about 5-7 reps with both hands and just starting to close the 250's. So, to determine real progress, I would suggest grips with known resistance.  In regards to having both hands un-equal, I think that's common for beginners and probably shows up if you're using dumbbells for lifts (instead of barbells where one hand/side can compensate for the other).  My recommendations:

- get grips with the resistance marked on them, you'll only need one of each weight you're working on (I only work one hand at a time)
- when lifting, see if your personal trainer agrees, use dumbbells so you're not overcompensating
- dead lifts are great grip exercises - last rep, hold on as long as you can, this will build your grip strength (same with pull ups)

Comment: I am trying to buy locally as I would like to get started as soon as possible(otherwise I would have ordered of ebay) so there seems to be slim pickings. Yes I do overcompensate with one had and one of the reasons why he suggested to work on my grip. We already do dead lifts(he wishes he could make me do them all day long lol). I will check around maybe I can find store with better hand grips but the ones I checked so far just sell the same brand.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind with grippers is making sure that you work all your fingers. If you hold them in the standard grip (spring by your thumb) you'll probably focus on the first three fingers, so if you turn them over (spring by your little finger) you will get the smaller fingers too.